# PyQt5 Custom Title Bar Doesn't Show

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8

I am trying to make my first program. I'm hoping for custom dark mode design, and that requires me to make a custom title bar.
I copied the code for the title bar from someone else, it worked perfectly - custom movable window.
I have carefully merged it with my previous code, though title bar doesn't appear.
Now my guess is I have to call it at the end of my code, but it ends up with errors, as I'm not sure how to properly call it.

*Note: removing the QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint part is NOT the answer, as it just brings back the stock Win title bar, that's supposed to be hidden and replaced by dark title bar.*

Part of code copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249552/12221725

Image:

[image: IMAGE _ THE look im aiming at]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit

#fCol = "#e0e0e0"
#bCol = "#212121"

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.textArea = QTextEdit("Lorem ipsum...")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textArea)
        self.textArea.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {color:white;background-color:#212121;border-radius:+16px;}")
        self.sans = QFont("Segoe UI",20)
        self.textArea.setFont(self.sans)
        self.btnLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Open"))
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Setup"))
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Find"))
        self.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {max-width:200px;color:#4fc3f7;background-color:#424242;border:2px solid #4fc3f7;border-radius:16px;font-size:35px;font-weight:bold;}" + "QPushButton:hover {color:#212121;background-color:#4fc3f7;}" + "QPushButton:pressed {color:white;background-color:#212121;border-color:white;}")
        self.status = QTextEdit()
        self.status.insertPlainText("Successfully loaded" + "\nOpen a file...")
        self.status.setReadOnly(1)
        self.status.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {color:white;background-color:#212121;border-radius:+16px;font-size:14px;max-width:200px;}")
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(self.status)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.btnLayout)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        #self.setFixedSize(650, 320)
        self.setFixedSize(800, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Py Program")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)# | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        #self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        #self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        #self.pressing = False
        print("MainWindow Loaded")
        #self.show()



class MyBar(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        print(self.parent.width())
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.title = QLabel("My Own Bar")

        btn_size = 35

        self.btn_close = QPushButton("x")
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.btn_close_clicked)
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(btn_size,btn_size)
        self.btn_close.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")

        self.btn_min = QPushButton("-")
        self.btn_min.clicked.connect(self.btn_min_clicked)
        self.btn_min.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_min.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.btn_max = QPushButton("+")
        self.btn_max.clicked.connect(self.btn_max_clicked)
        self.btn_max.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_max.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.title.setFixedHeight(35)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_min)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_max)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_close)

        self.title.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;color: white;")
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False
        print("MyBar Loaded")


    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(MyBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.parent.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                self.parent.width(),
                                self.parent.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False


    def btn_close_clicked(self):
        self.parent.close()

    def btn_max_clicked(self):
        self.parent.showMaximized()

    def btn_min_clicked(self):
        self.parent.showMinimized()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
    app.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:#424242;border-radius:12px;}")
    app.setFont(QFont("Consolas"))
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1) do not create a new post with the same question, 2) You must use `@username` to notify me of your message, 3) be patient, if I did not reopen it I would reopen the community.

Comment: Since it took little time to mark this as a duplicate, and long time to get additional response, I thought this post was buried. I took my time to make sure the second post would contain more information to differentiate from the "original" post. Thx for reopening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not created or placed a Bar() inside the window. You must also restructure your layout so that the titlebar is displayed at the top and your content at the bottom using a QVBoxLayout.

On the other hand I have improved the original titleBar so that it is not necessary to set the parent directly but instead use the window():

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QLabel

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.textArea = QTextEdit("Lorem ipsum...")
        hlayout.addWidget(self.textArea)
        self.textArea.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {color:white;background-color:#212121;border-radius:+16px;}")
        self.sans = QFont("Segoe UI",20)
        self.textArea.setFont(self.sans)
        self.btnLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Open"))
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Setup"))
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Find"))
        self.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {max-width:200px;color:#4fc3f7;background-color:#424242;border:2px solid #4fc3f7;border-radius:16px;font-size:35px;font-weight:bold;}" + "QPushButton:hover {color:#212121;background-color:#4fc3f7;}" + "QPushButton:pressed {color:white;background-color:#212121;border-color:white;}")
        self.status = QTextEdit()
        self.status.insertPlainText("Successfully loaded" + "\nOpen a file...")
        self.status.setReadOnly(1)
        self.status.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {color:white;background-color:#212121;border-radius:+16px;font-size:14px;max-width:200px;}")
        self.btnLayout.addWidget(self.status)
        self.setFixedSize(800, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Py app")
        hlayout.addLayout(self.btnLayout)
        
        custom_titlebar = TitleBar()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(custom_titlebar)
        lay.addLayout(hlayout)



class TitleBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__(parent)
 
        self.title = QLabel("My Own Bar")

        btn_size = 35

        self.btn_close = QPushButton("x")
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.btn_close_clicked)
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(btn_size,btn_size)
        self.btn_close.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")

        self.btn_min = QPushButton("-")
        self.btn_min.clicked.connect(self.btn_min_clicked)
        self.btn_min.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_min.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.btn_max = QPushButton("+")
        self.btn_max.clicked.connect(self.btn_max_clicked)
        self.btn_max.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_max.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.title.setFixedHeight(35)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.title.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;color: white;")

        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        lay.addWidget(self.title)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_min)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_max)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_close)

        self.pressing = False
        self.dragPosition = QPoint()

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(TitleBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.window().width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = event.globalPos()
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = event.globalPos()
            delta = self.end - self.start
            self.window().move(self.window().pos() + delta)
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False


    def btn_close_clicked(self):
        self.window().close()

    def btn_max_clicked(self):
        self.window().showMaximized()

    def btn_min_clicked(self):
        self.window().showMinimized()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))
    app.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:#424242;border-radius:12px;}")
    app.setFont(QFont("Consolas"))
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution that I'll probably end up using, however, it doesn't answer what went wrong while merging my code with the one from StackOv. As I said in my post, it seems that in my code, the title bar class doesn't get called at all. I'm curious why.

Comment: @bielovymaľovanástena mmm, I don't understand you, have you used my code? Have you read my answer ?, I point there because your code does not work and how it should be solved: *The problem is that you have not created or placed a Bar() inside the window*

Comment: Thanks, I looked at your code but I focused on the bottom part of the code... Now I see you've written Bar() in your post, I must have read it simply as bar. With that, this is finally solved, much thanks