# PyQt6/PySide6: window move doesn't work properly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm trying to create a window with a custom bar on top.
For this I am using the following bar code: (`bar.py`)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QPointF
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon

```
class CustomBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_window = main_window

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # ------- title -------
        self.title = QLabel("MyApp")
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(100)

        # ------- minimize button -------
        self.minimize_button = QPushButton()
        self.minimize_button.setIcon(QIcon("media\\ui\\icons\\enabled_button.png"))
        self.minimize_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);")
        self.minimize_button.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
        self.minimize_button.setFixedSize(16, 16)
        self.minimize_button.clicked.connect(self.minimize_window)

        # ------- close button -------
        self.close_button = QPushButton()
        self.close_button.setIcon(QIcon("media\\ui\\icons\\disabled_button.png"))
        self.close_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);")
        self.close_button.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
        self.minimize_button.setFixedSize(16, 16)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.minimize_button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.close_button)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.current_position = QPointF(0, 0)

    def minimize_window(self):
        self.main_window.showMinimized()

    def close_window(self):
        self.main_window.close()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.current_position = self.mapToGlobal(event.position())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        new_position = self.mapToGlobal(event.position())
        movement = new_position - self.current_position
        print(self.current_position, new_position, movement, "-------------------", sep="\n")
        self.main_window.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(movement).x(), self.mapToGlobal(movement).y(),
                                     self.main_window.width(), self.main_window.height())
        self.current_position = new_position
```

I have created a `MainPage` widget as the main content of the window:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout

from gui.toggle_button import ToggleButton
from functools import partial


class MainPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        super(MainPage, self).__init__()
        self.bot = bot  # an instance of the main program class

        self.buttons = {}
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        for i in self.bot.settings["toggles"]:  # creating buttons for each available switch
            print(i)
            btn = ToggleButton(self.bot.settings["toggles"][i]["name"])
            btn.set_state(self.bot.settings["toggles"][i]["value"])
            btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.bot.toggle_setting, i))
            btn.clicked.connect(self.bot.menu.update)
            btn.clicked.connect(self.update_buttons)
            self.layout.addWidget(btn)
            self.buttons[i] = btn

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def update_buttons(self):  # some switches enable/disable other switches, so you need to update the state of all switches.
        for i in self.buttons:
            self.buttons[i].set_state(self.bot.settings["toggles"][i]["value"])
```

`QPushButton` custom widget code (`ToggleButton`):

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon


class ToggleButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.button_size = QSize(25, 25)
        self.is_enabled = True
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 25))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(200, 25))

        self.setText(name)
        self.setIcon(QIcon("media\\ui\\icons\\enabled_button.png"))
        self.setIconSize(self.button_size)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: left; border: 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);")

    def set_disabled(self):
        self.setIcon(QIcon("media\\ui\\icons\\disabled_button.png"))
        self.setIconSize(self.button_size)
        self.is_enabled = False

    def set_enabled(self):
        self.setIcon(QIcon("media\\ui\\icons\\enabled_button.png"))
        self.setIconSize(self.button_size)
        self.is_enabled = True

    def set_state(self, state: bool):
        self.set_enabled() if state else self.set_disabled()
```

And finally, the main widget:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from gui.main_menu import MainPage
from gui.bar import CustomBar


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # disable window frames

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.main_widget = MainPage(bot)
        self.bar = CustomBar(self) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.bar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


def init_ui(bot):
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow(bot)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

The interface looks pretty much as I expected, however, when I try to move it, the window moves straight down to the right, regardless of mouse movement: https://youtu.be/Ont_UsDcA0c

But judging by the console output, the desired position of the window is determined correctly, and, as I understand it, I am using the `.mapToGlobal()` function incorrectly.
Console output:

```
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(508.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(509.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(1.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(509.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(510.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(1.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(510.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(510.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(0.000000, -1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(510.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(511.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(1.000000, 1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(511.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(512.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(1.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(512.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(511.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(511.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(511.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(0.000000, -1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(511.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(510.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, 1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(510.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(508.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-2.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(508.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(508.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(0.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(508.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(507.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, -1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(507.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(506.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, 1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(506.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(505.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(505.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(505.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(0.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(505.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(504.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, -1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(504.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(503.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, 1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(503.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(502.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(502.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(502.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(0.000000, 0.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(502.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(501.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, -1.000000)
-------------------
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(501.000000, 196.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(500.000000, 197.000000)
PySide6.QtCore.QPointF(-1.000000, 1.000000)
-------------------
```

I took this code as the basis for the custom bar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249552/18196171

No matter how much I compared them, I did not find tangible differences that could change the result so much.

What could be the problem?