# how to have custom title bar without loosing resizability of window in PyQt?

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to build a custom title bar, but the problem is that whenever I try to do it, I lose the ability to resize the window. Like those arrows when you go to the borders of your window. Is it possible to set them up somehow? I have an example of the script(which is not mine), but it has the same problem as mine. Can somebody help? Maybe there is a way to change title bar stylesheets using QDialog or QMainWindow so you will have those basic functionalities of a window?

I tried checking this code [Custom Titlebar with frame in PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241612/custom-titlebar-with-frame-in-pyqt5) but window there still doesn't have arrows to resize window...

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TitleBar(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight)
        self.minimize=QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.minimize.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('min.png'))
        self.maximize=QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.maximize.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('max.png'))
        close=QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        close.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('close.png'))
        self.minimize.setMinimumHeight(10)
        close.setMinimumHeight(10)
        self.maximize.setMinimumHeight(10)
        label=QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label.setText("Window Title")
        self.setWindowTitle("Window Title")
        hbox=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(label)
        hbox.addWidget(self.minimize)
        hbox.addWidget(self.maximize)
        hbox.addWidget(close)
        hbox.insertStretch(1,500)
        hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.maxNormal=False
        close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.minimize.clicked.connect(self.showSmall)
        self.maximize.clicked.connect(self.showMaxRestore)

    def showSmall(self):
        box.showMinimized()

    def showMaxRestore(self):
        if(self.maxNormal):
            box.showNormal()
            self.maxNormal= False
            self.maximize.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('img/max.png'))
        else:
            box.showMaximized()
            self.maxNormal=True
            self.maximize.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('img/max2.png'))

    def close(self):
        box.close()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            box.moving = True
            box.offset = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        if box.moving: box.move(event.globalPos()-box.offset)


class Frame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.m_mouse_down= False
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.m_titleBar = TitleBar(self)
        self.m_content = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.m_titleBar)
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        vbox.setSpacing(0)
        layout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.m_content)
        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        vbox.addLayout(layout)


    def contentWidget(self):
        return self.m_content

    def titleBar(self):
        return self.m_titleBar

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        self.m_old_pos = event.pos()
        self.m_mouse_down = event.button()== Qt.LeftButton

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        x=event.x()
        y=event.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        m_mouse_down=False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    box = Frame()
    box.move(60,60)
    l=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(box.contentWidget())
    l.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    box.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Since the frame of a window is what normally allows resizing, using a frameless window obviously prevents that. You need to implement that based on mouse position or add appropriate tools like QSizeGrip as child widgets.

Comment: I see, but if I set frames then I have this default title bar which I don't like and there is no way as far as I googled to change "setStyleSheet" of the default frame... So I guess only on mouse position option left since I don't really like how QSizeGrip works. But if I set the mouse position how do I get this arrow on the border of the window when I hover over it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't "like" about QSizeGrip? If you only need to update the cursor based on its position, ensure that you get mouse movements (without buttons pressed) by setting the `mouseTracking` property, then override `mouseMoveEvent()` and verify the currently pressed `buttons()` of that event: if it has no buttons pressed, update the cursor (see the `cursor` property of all QWidgets), otherwise begin the geometry change. Note that since Qt5 the QWindow class (which you can get from `self.windowHandle()`) supports the `startSystemResize()` function.

Comment: There is no big problem with QSizeGrip, I just feel it's more user-friendly when you have arrows on the borders of the window and you can scale each side individually, rather than having only one grip in the corner to scale the whole window.