# PyQt6 custom title bar causes window to move differently from the cursor

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

This is about my GUI program that I have been working on for over 2 months.

[image]

I have finally completed it and I have posted it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287608/gui-tic-tac-toe-game-with-six-ai-players-part-1-the-ui) and I have also opened a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/Estrangeling/Tic-Tac-Toe) for it. I have implemented everything I originally intended, and I have fixed every bug that I found.

Now I want to customize the title bar, but somehow it isn't working. Because the project is massive, it contains 113714 characters in the scripts alone, I can't post the complete code here. I also can't post a minimal reproducible example because I have no idea what caused the bug, the code I adapted is working properly, but when I put the custom title bar to the main window with all other stuff, it malfunctions.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249552/16383578), and I adapted it to PyQt6:

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(MyBar())
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 400)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.pressing = False


class MyBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(MyBar, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.title = QLabel("My Own Bar")

        btn_size = 35

        self.btn_close = QPushButton("x")
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.btn_close_clicked)
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_close.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")

        self.btn_min = QPushButton("-")
        self.btn_min.clicked.connect(self.btn_min_clicked)
        self.btn_min.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_min.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.btn_max = QPushButton("+")
        self.btn_max.clicked.connect(self.btn_max_clicked)
        self.btn_max.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_max.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.title.setFixedHeight(35)
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_min)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_max)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_close)

        self.title.setStyleSheet(
            """
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        """
        )
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(MyBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.window().width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
        self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        delta = self.end - self.start
        self.window().setGeometry(
            self.mapToGlobal(delta).x(),
            self.mapToGlobal(delta).y(),
            self.window().width(),
            self.window().height(),
        )
        self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False

    def btn_close_clicked(self):
        self.window().close()

    def btn_max_clicked(self):
        self.window().showMaximized()

    def btn_min_clicked(self):
        self.window().showMinimized()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

It is working properly.

So I tried to add it to my project, but somehow it doesn't work properly, the relevant code is below:

```
class SquareButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setFont(FONT)
        self.setText(text)
        self.setFixedSize(32, 32)


class TitleBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name: str, exitfunc: Callable) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.hbox = make_hbox(self, 0)
        self.name = name
        self.exitfunc = exitfunc
        self.setObjectName("Title")
        self.add_icon()
        self.add_title()
        self.add_buttons()
        self.setFixedHeight(35)

    def add_icon(self) -> None:
        self.icon = QLabel()
        self.icon.setPixmap(GLOBALS["Logo"])
        self.icon.setFixedSize(32, 32)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.icon)
        self.hbox.addStretch()

    def add_title(self) -> None:
        self.title = Label(self.name)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.title)
        self.hbox.addStretch()

    def add_buttons(self) -> None:
        self.minimize_button = SquareButton("—")
        self.minimize_button.clicked.connect(self.minimize)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.minimize_button)
        self.close_button = SquareButton("X")
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.exitfunc)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.close_button)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(e.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent):
        if self.pressing:
            print(e.pos())
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(e.pos())
            delta = self.end - self.start
            self.window().setGeometry(
                self.mapToGlobal(delta).x(),
                self.mapToGlobal(delta).y(),
                self.window().width(),
                self.window().height(),
            )
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self.pressing = False

    def minimize(self) -> None:
        self.window().showMinimized()
```

I don't know what caused the issue, the code should work, but when I ran it, and tried to move the window by dragging the title bar, the window moves erratically, its movement doesn't correspond to the movement of the cursor. At first it seemed to follow the cursor but lags behind a little bit, and then it doesn't follow the cursor at all.

The window has a tendency to move to the lower right, and if the mouse moves up the window somehow moves down, and the window will move below the lower edge of the screen, the window seems to move in the same direction as the cursor horizontally, but not the same distance.

So I tried to debug it by printing the positions of the events, and the working example prints all positive coordinates:

```
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(575, 17)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(575, 17)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(575, 17)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(575, 16)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(574, 17)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(575, 17)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(574, 17)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(571, 16)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(575, 16)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(575, 17)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(571, 15)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(573, 17)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(568, 16)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(567, 15)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(570, 14)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(567, 13)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(564, 11)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(564, 13)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(565, 13)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(565, 16)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(562, 13)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(564, 11)
```

But somehow the code when used in my project prints some negative coordinates:

```
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(55, -322)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(51, -327)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(47, -330)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(41, -334)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(37, -337)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(35, -341)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(30, -343)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(30, -346)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(29, -348)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(26, -351)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(25, -352)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(25, -354)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(23, -356)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(19, -358)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(16, -362)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(14, -365)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(9, -368)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(7, -372)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(3, -374)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-2, -378)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-1, -379)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-7, -383)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-7, -386)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-10, -388)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-14, -392)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-17, -394)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-20, -399)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-22, -401)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-25, -403)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-30, -407)
PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(-31, -409)
```

I have packaged the full code to a zip file and uploaded to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wDUiAvu47cUbS-8omZeiqZe--FFREUy5/view?usp=sharing), so that you may run the code and debug it. Because I use pickle data files, you may need to run `analyze_tic_tac_toe_states.py` to generate the data files before running `main.py` to call up the window.

What caused the strange bug and how to fix it?

Comment: Questions should always be self-contained, so please take your time and provide a valid [mre] we can easily copy/paste/run. I also suggest you to remove the initial part of your question as knowing about your project is irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `QWidget.mapToGlobal(e.pos())` sometimes outputs incorrect values, it may be related to pending geometry changes which causes invalid (probably random) values of transformation matrix, I guess. To avoid erratic movement use `QMouseEvent.globalPosition().toPoint()`.

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt6.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PyQt6.QtCore import QRect, QPoint

class TitleBar(QWidget):

    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self.start = e.globalPosition().toPoint()
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = e.globalPosition().toPoint()
            delta = self.end - self.start
            self.window().setGeometry(
                self.mapToGlobal(delta).x(),
                self.mapToGlobal(delta).y(),
                self.window().width(),
                self.window().height(),
            )
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self.pressing = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = TitleBar()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Or you can save offset from topleft corner of widget (local coordinate) once on mouse press and move window to global coordinate offseted by this value and forget about `start` and `end`

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt6.QtGui import QMouseEvent
from PyQt6.QtCore import QRect

class TitleBar(QWidget):

    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self.offset = e.pos()
        self.pressing = True
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent):
        if self.pressing:
            geometry = self.geometry()
            newGeometry = QRect(e.globalPosition().toPoint() - self.offset, geometry.size())
            self.setGeometry(newGeometry)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self.pressing = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = TitleBar()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Another possibility is to call the underlying QWindow (`self.window().windowHandler()`) [`startSystemMove()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#startSystemMove).